# Function returns a promise rather than the object it should return

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was writing a MEAN stack application when I came across a rather peculiar error  that I don't quite understand.

One of the functions I wrote should return a regular JSON object with certain parameters that will be set in the execution of the function. However, that is not what happens. It instead returns a promise object.

I created a user model, and then created some methods/functions for it. The function in question that returns a promise is the `validate` function.

What this function does is simply that it makes sure that the data the user entered is in check! You can tell from the code in `user.js` that it merely checks the length of the input data as well as match it to some predefined regular expressions to see if the data is within acceptable limits (in order not to cause problems later).

I call this function when a user registers which happens in the register function in `registerController.js` which also should find if the user already exists (has created an account before) or if the username he chose is taken (username exists) after that it sends them a confirmation email containing a link that is their temporaryToken. The route that leads the user to register is in `registerRoutes.js`. I tried logging the value of the objects received from the functions `checkData` and `validate`. checkData returns a normal object while validate returns a promise even though it shouldn't.

Here is the user file `user.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    firstName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    confirmed:{
        type: Boolean,
        default:false,
        required: true
    },
    temporaryToken:{
        type: String,
        default: "NO_TOKEN",
        required: true
    }
});

userSchema.method({
    checkData: function() {
        let checkData = {};
        checkData.missing = [];
        checkData.wrongType = [];
        checkData.success = true;
        if(!this.username)
        {
            checkData.success = false;
            checkData.missing.push("username");
        }
        if(!this.email)
        {
            checkData.success = false;
            checkData.missing.push("email");
        }
        if(!this.password)
        {
            checkData.success = false;
            checkData.missing.push("password");
        }
        if(!this.firstName)
        {
            checkData.success = false;
            checkData.missing.push("firstName");
        }
        if(!this.lastName)
        {
            checkData.success = false;
            checkData.missing.push("lastName");
        }
        return checkData;
    },
    validate: function() {
        let validation = {};
        validation.errors = [];
        validation.success = true;
        if(this.username.length < 2 || this.username.length > 35)
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "username",
                "message": "Invalid length of username. Username must be between 2 and 35 characters long."
            });
        }
        if(this.email.length < 6 || this.username.length > 256)
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "email",
                "message": "Invalid length of email. Email must be between 6 and 256 characters long."
            });
        }
        if(this.password.length < 8 || this.password.length > 50)
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "password",
                "message": "Invalid length of password. Password must be between 6 and 256 characters long."
            });
        }
        if(this.firstName.length < 2 || this.firstName.length > 35)
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "firstName",
                "message": "Invalid length of first name. First name must be between 2 and 35 characters long."
            });
        }
        if(this.lastName.length < 2 || this.lastName.length > 35)
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "lastName",
                "message": "Invalid length of last name. Last name must be between 2 and 35 characters long."
            });
        }
        let usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9$#@%`'"\.]+$/
        if(!usernameRegex.test(this.username))
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "username",
                "message": "Invalid format of username. Username can only contain Alphanumeric characters and $ # @ % ` ' \" and .."
            });
        }
        let emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if(!emailRegex.test(this.email))
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "email",
                "message": "Invalid format and email. Email has to be in the form example@domain.com."
            })
        }
        let passwordRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9$#@%`'"\.]+$/;
        if(!passwordRegex.test(this.password))
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "email",
                "message": "Invalid format of password. Password an only contain Alphanumeric characters and $ # @ % ` ' \" and .."
            });
        }
        let nameRegex = /^[A-Z][a-z-]+$/;
        if(!nameRegex.test(this.firstName))
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "firstName",
                "message": "Invalid format of first name. First Name can only contain English letters and hyphens (-)."
            });
        }
        if(!nameRegex.test(this.middleName))
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "middleName",
                "message": "Invalid format of middle name. Middle Name can only contain English letters and hyphens (-)."
            });
        }
        if(!nameRegex.test(this.lastName))
        {
            validation.success = false;
            validation.errors.push({
                "field": "lastName",
                "message": "Invalid format of last name. Last Name can only contain English letters and hyphens (-)."
            });
        }
        return validation;
    },
    capitalizeNames: function() {
        this.firstName = this.firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.firstName.slice(1);
        this.lastName = this.lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.lastName.slice(1);
    }
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

Here is the register controller file `registerController.js`

```
const User = require("../model/user.js");
const system = require("../middleware/system.js");
const mails = require("../../config/mails.js");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let registerController = {
    register: function(req, res, next) {
        let newUser = new User ({
            "username": req.body.username,
            "email": req.body.email,
            "password": req.body.password,
            "firstName": req.body.firstName,
            "lastName": req.body.lastName,
        });
        let check = newUser.checkData();
        if(!check.success)
        {
            res.status(400).json(check);
            next();
            return;
        }
        newUser.capitalizeNames();
        let validity = newUser.validate();
        console.log(validity); // "Promise { <pending> }"
        if(!validity.success)
        {
            res.status(400).json(validity);
            next();
            return;
        }
        newUser.findOne({"username": newUser.username}, function(err, foundUser1) {
            if(err)
            {
                system.handleServerError(res);
                next();
                return;
            }
            if(foundUser1)
            {
                res.status(403).json({
                    "success": false,
                    "message": "The user with the name " + newUser.username + " already exists. Please choose another name."
                });
                next();
                return;
            }
            newUser.findOne({"email": newUser.email}, function(err, foundUser2) {
                if(err)
                {
                    system.handleServerError(res);
                    next();
                    return;
                }
                if(foundUser2)
                {
                    res.status(403).json({
                        "success": false,
                        "message": "The user with the email " + newUser.email + " already exists. If you already have an account, please log in."
                    });
                    next();
                    return;
                }
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    newUser.temporaryToken = jwt.sign({
                        "email": newUser.email
                    }, "confirm", {
                        expiresIn: 60*60*24*365
                    });
                    newUser.save(function(err, product, numAffected) {
                        if(err)
                        {
                            system.handleServerError(res);
                            next();
                            return;
                        }
                        // SEND EMAIL TO USER
                        res.status(200).json({
                            "success": true,
                            "message": "Your registration has been completed successfully. A confirmation link has been sent to your email. Please use that link to actvate your account and login."
                        });
                        next();
                        return;
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = registerController;
```

Here is the routes file `registerRoutes.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const registerController = require("../controllers/registerController.js")

router.post("/api/register", registerController.register);

module.exports = router;
```

Please tell me if there is anything other information that I can provide or clarify. And thank you all for your time. :)

Comment: What is the expected result of `return;`?

Comment: @gust271314 ```return;``` statements in ```registerController.js``` don't return a value. They only exit the function. The value that is returned wrong is in ```user.js``` in the function ```validate```. It should be regular JSON object rather than a Promise object.

Comment: Have not tried mongoose. Have you tried getting the `Promise` value using `.then()`?

Comment: @guest271314 Of course, but that is not the problem. There shouldn't be a Promise in the first place. This is a function that I defined myself. It shouldn't return a Promise at all.

Comment: Does not mongoose use a `Promise` based pattern?

Comment: @guest271314 It does, but the function in question is not a mongoose function. It is a function that I defined myself.

Comment: Again, have no experience with mongoose. What is the issue with using `.then()`?

Comment: @guest271314 You don't seem to understand my question. I wrote a function from scratch that should return an regular JSON Object. When that function is called it returns a ```Promise``` object instead. The function is called on an instance of a mongoose model. It is NOT a mongoose function. ```.then()``` works as it should, but there should be no ```Promise``` object at all.

Comment: @guest271314 In short, there is a Promise object being created by my function, when there should be NONE at all.

Comment: That appears to be the design of mongoose?

Comment: @guest271314 If you don't understand what I'm saying, please read the ```validate``` function in the ```user.js``` file in the posted code. Tell me if anything in this function should return a ```Promise```.

Comment: Unlike your checkData(), doesn't your validate() go to the server and check the database?  If so, you need to wait for the response before you try to access it.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Niether ```checkData()``` nor ```validate()``` check the database at any point in their execution. Every function contained within them should be synchronous and they should both be completely sequential in their execution. There is nothing that runs asynchronously to wait for. I tried using async/await but the server hung, and no response was delivered (much like an infinite loop, even though there are no loops or server/database/API calls).

Comment: OK.  I notice your usernameRegex does not have a `;` at the end of the line.  Plus, those regexes are pretty complicated.  Why don't you try to remove these regexes and add back 1 at a time while you test?  Maybe 1 of them is causing a problem.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Thank you very much for your comment! I added the semicolon ```;``` and removed all the regexes. After testing again, I still get the same problem. ```validate()``` still returns a Promise. I then tried something else. I removed everything in the function and left a ```return {success: true}``` and its still didn't work. After that I changed its name from ```validate()``` to ```validator()``` and it worked. ```validate()``` must have been a predefined function in one of the modules I'm using I don't know which one though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the naming of the function.

`validate()` is already defined in the mongoose module. Calling it on an instance of the user model called the native mongoose function that expected a callback, and therefore returned a promise.

Thankfully, changing `validate()` to `validator()` solved the problem.